# Add character vector based on reference data frame parameters

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame df1:

```
chr = c( 1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
point = c (257,752,135,1650,252,756,1230,1710)
df1 = data.frame(chr, point)

  chr point
1   1   257
2   1   752
3   1   135
4   1  1650
5   2   252
6   2   756
7   2  1230
8   2  1710
```

I would like to add a new column to this called `name`. The name to be allocated comes from a reference data frame df2:

```
chrB = c( 1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
txstart = c(0,501,1001,1501,0,501,1001,1501)
txstop = c(500,1000,1500,2000,500,1000,1500,2000)
name2 = c("F","W","Q","G","V","S","L","Y") 

  chrB txstart txstop name2
1    2       0    500    F
2    2     501   1000    W
3    2    1001   1500    Q
4    2    1501   2000    G
5    1       0    500    V
6    1     501   1000    S
7    1    1001   1500    L
8    1    1501   2000    Y
```

Where `chr` in df1 is the same as `chrB` in `df2` AND `point` in `df1` lies between values `txstart` and `txstop` the `name2` in `df2` should be added to `df1`.  result I would like is below:

```
  chr point  name
1   1   257     V
2   1   752     S
3   1   135     L
4   1  1650     Y
5   2   252     F
6   2   756     W
7   2  1230     Q
8   2  1710     G
```

Any help much appreciated!!!

Comment: Where does the `V, S, L, Y` etc come from based on the input example dataset?

Comment: btw `df2 = data.frame(chrB,txstart, txstop,name)` should be `df2 = data.frame(chrB,txstart, txstop,name2`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the updated dataset only the `foverlaps` method works:

```
dt1 <- data.table(chr, mp1 = point, mp2 = point, 
                  key = c("chr","mp1", "mp2"))
dt2 <- data.table(chrB, txstart, txstop, name2, 
                  key = c("chrB","txstart", "txstop"))

foverlaps(dt1, dt2, type="within")[, .(chr, midpoint=mp1, name=name2)][]
```

which gives:

```
   chr midpoint name
1:   1      135    F
2:   1      257    F
3:   1      752    W
4:   1     1650    G
5:   2      252    V
6:   2      756    S
7:   2     1230    L
8:   2     1710    Y
```

---

**Old answer:**

When you want to look whether the midpoint is between the start and stop point of `df2`, you could use:

```
df1$name <- df2$name2[match(df1$chr,df2$chrB) & 
                        df1$midpoint > df2$txstart & 
                        df1$midpoint < df2$txstop]
```

which gives:

```
> df1
  chr midpoint name
1   1      250    F
2   1      750    W
3   1     1250    Q
4   1     1750    G
5   2      250    V
6   2      750    S
7   2     1250    L
8   2     1750    Y
```

---

As an alternative approach, you could use the `foverlaps` function from the *data.table* package:

```
library(data.table)

dt1 <- data.table(chr, mp1 = midpoint, mp2 = midpoint, key = c("chr","mp1", "mp2"))
dt2 <- data.table(chrB, txstart, txstop, name2, key = c("chrB","txstart", "txstop"))

foverlaps(dt1, dt2, type="within", nomatch=0L)[, .(chr, midpoint=mp1, name=name2)][]
```

which gives the same result:

```
   chr midpoint name
1:   1      250    F
2:   1      750    W
3:   1     1250    Q
4:   1     1750    G
5:   2      250    V
6:   2      750    S
7:   2     1250    L
8:   2     1750    Y
```